# Problems running jenkins slave via jnlp on fedora 23

Tags: java, jenkins, jnlp, fedora-23

I have installed jenkins on fedora 23 using the standard package manager (dnf).  On a separate fedora 23, I am attempting to create a slave instance using "Launch Slave Agents via Java JNLP".

As per directions I downloaded the slave.jar file from the jenkins master instance and ran

`java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://${HOST}:${PORT}/computer/${SLAVE}/slave-agent.jnlp`

and I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set value to a final field 'hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main.urls'.
    at org.kohsuke.args4j.spi.Setters.create(Setters.java:32)
    at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:34)
    at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:94)
    at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main._main(Main.java:123)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:228)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:192)
```

Is this a known problem? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a work around?

Comment: Can you check whats inside this jnlp? If it looks valid? Have you fully configured your  jenkins master yet? Things like missing hostname etc could maybe mess up the contents of the jnlp? Edit: Check if the url in the <argument> block *after* the <argument>-url</argument> block is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Had to copy my old slave.jar from my previous Jenkins virtual server to get this to work.  Renamed it to slave.jar.linux and had my clients point to that file.  I used a version from my Redhat 6.5 build using Jenkins 1.619 on my Fedora Core 23 box which is running 1.625.3 to work around this issue.